# Hiding or rewriting URLs

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

I'm currently using Apache TomEE, apache-tomcat implementation for JavaEE webapps. My question now is, is it possible to manipulate urls in order to hide information and parameters or rewrite them so that the urls is nicer

For example, can I modify the following url:

```
myWebApp/Pagination?page=15
```

into this, and still be able to retrieve the page parameter

```
myWebApp/Page/15
```

I looked at The rewrite Valve but I don't know, it could be overshooting my needings

Comment: Are you using JSF?

Comment: no, just plain jsp/jstl